# Strange tab completion behavior with virtualenvwrapper workon command

Tags: virtualenvwrapper, tab-completion

I use `virtualenvwrapper` for setting up virtual environments, and as with anything I do in a terminal, I rely heavily on the time-saving magic of tab completion.

In the [terminator terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminator_(terminal_emulator)) that I use on Ubuntu 16.04, tab completion works normally for the `workon` command (i.e., I type `work`, and hit tab to get `workon` - typing that much is necessary to get a unique completion). The problem comes when I try to use tab completion for the name of the virtual environment: it works, but not as expected. For example, if I have a virtualenv `testenv`, and in my terminal I type `workon test` and hit tab, it will show `testenv` as the only completion, but I will need to add (or remove) at least one character before it will complete the name. So, as an example that strangely works:

1. I type `workon test` at a command prompt.
2. I hit tab and see the output `testenv` displayed (but the command in the prompt is not completed, and I still see `$ workon test`.
3. I delete the `t` so that I have `$ workon tes` in the prompt.
4. I hit tab again, and I get the full completion `$ workon testenv`.

After tab completion works one time, it will continue to work for that terminal session, so if I type `$ workon test` again, it will complete `test` to `testenv` the first time I hit tab.

This does not make things unusable, and naturally I am capable of typing the entire command out without any completion. But the fact that completion works, but works differently than seemingly everywhere else, has been driving me crazy on a daily basis for quite a while.

Is this a bug? The expected behavior? Is there a fix for this? My searches so far have come up empty.

Comment: I have the same problem. Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Actually problem was solved when I added initialization to `.bashrc`:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

As described in [docs](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file).